# What are non standard attributes use for?

Tags: html, attributes

Today, I was parsing google's HTML and faced with some non standard HTML's attributes. Take a look at this:

[image]

As you know, there isn't either `jsname` or `jsdata` or .. attributes in HTML. Well I'm just curious, what google use them for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**jsaction** attribute is added by Google's jsaction library. 
It's source code can be found on project's GitHub page: https://github.com/google/jsaction

I have no idea about the other attributes though.

Comment: Is this "legal" (okay, "valid")? I could be wrong (it's happened before), but my understanding is that "custom" attributes had to include a "-" like: "js-action", or "js-name". Isn't there a risk there would be a conflict if tomorrow (someday) one of these were added as a standard attribute?

Comment: You’re talking about custom HTML tags. However, for valid HTML you do need to prefix custom attributes with `data-`.